# Reducing $x^{p-1}$ mod $p$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I read a comment in an algebraic number theory text that the reduction of $f=x^{p-1}-1\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ reduces in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ to a product of distinct linear factors. Why is this true? I know that $x^{p^n}-x$ is the product of all the distinct irreducible factors in $\mathbb{F}_p$ of degree $d$ where $d$ runs through all divisors of $n$, but not sure if and how this applies.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of $p$-adics ? $\Bbb{F}_p^\times$ is a group with $p-1$ elements thus all of them have order dividing $p-1$ ie. they are roots of $x^{p-1}-1\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ and a polynomial of degree $p-1$ with $p-1$ distinct roots splits completely. The interesting parts is that $x^{p-1}-1\in \Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ splits completely too because each root $\bmod p$ of a separable polynomial lifts to $\Bbb{Z}_p$ using Hensel lemma's algorithm.

Comment: Take $n=1$, then there is exactly one value of $d$, namely $d=1$.  Now read your statement “I know that...” again, applied to $x^p - x$.  Factor out $x$.

Comment: oh, duh, thanks.